# unable to retrieve exact decimal value from .xlsx file cell using python which has some formula embedded

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsx, xlrd

I am trying to retrieve value from excel file(.xlsx) using python which has some formula embedded columns.

```
A7: 90618.17
B7: 72.625
AC: = A7*B7 giving 6581144.59625
```

I tried reading the value of cell AC using different packages (openpyxl, xlrd, pandas), but none of these are able to retrieve the exact value. 
Reading it gives 6581144.5962499995.

Excepted value is 6581144.59625 which is same as the displayed value in the cell AC.
Our requirement can't be fulfilled by rounding off the value. 
Please suggest some way.

Comment: that's a floating-point error you'll find eventually in any programming language. Take a look https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/floatingpoint.html . Value is still most likely good to use, though.

Comment: did you read the cell's display format and try to round off according to that? the data should be correct (subject to floating point margin)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are in for a quick&dirty solution...
...I think there may be a more mathematical solution:
It prints: 6581144.59625

```
x = float( 6581144.5962499995)
y = float("{0:.5f}".format(x))
print(y)
```